# Evaluating (False is False) is returning False in specific cases

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I am encountering a strange problem in Python, where evaluating a condition involving a `np.linalg.norm` value is causing issues. This is my test script:

```
import numpy as np

def isGoalReached():
    start = np.array([4, 5, 6])
    goal = np.array([17, 18, 19])
    dist = np.linalg.norm(start - goal)
    return (dist < 0.5)

print (isGoalReached())
print (isGoalReached() == 0)
print (isGoalReached() is False)
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
False
```

If I remove the `np.linalg.norm` part, and rewrite so:

```
import numpy as np

def isGoalReached():
    dist = 123.456
    return (dist < 0.5)

print (isGoalReached())
print (isGoalReached() == 0)
print (isGoalReached() is False)
```

**Output**:

```
False
True
True
```

What is causing this very strange behavior? I am on Python 3.7.3 (Anaconda)

Comment: Weird indeed, but contrary to what you’ve said this is not a problem, since you’re not supposed to compare boolean values (via `is` or otherwise) at all.

Comment: One of them is a Python bool the other is `numpy.bool_`. Their types are different.

Comment: I just can see a normal behavior as per [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems np.linalg.norm returns a `numpy.float64`, and when you do the comparison, the type is `numpy.bool_`.

```
In [83]: np.bool_?                                                                                      
Init signature: np.bool_(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
Boolean type (True or False), stored as a byte.
```

That is why `is` doesn't work. If you add

```
return bool(dist < 0.5)
```

it would work as you expect here.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the return values of the `id()` function.

It says in the docs:

> **id(object)**
>
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer
>   which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during
>   its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the
>   same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
>   memory.

Even if you have only booleans and not some numpy types, you are not guaranteed to always get the same id for them.

Use `==` to compare booleans, not `is`.

Comment: “Use `==` to compare booleans” — No, really, please don’t, at least not to compare with literals. Writing `== True` or `== False` is nonsensical.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `if x == True` and `if x == False` can be shortened to `if x` and `if not x`, but if you have two booleans x and y then you should write `x == y` instead of `x is y`

Comment: Not “can be”, *should* be. That’s my point. And as for comparing two boolean variables (such as `x == y`), I can count on one hand the number of times I’ve had to do this in more than two decades of programming. It’s almost never required for good code.